# html attributes not working with js and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select the div with class of keys when the respective key is pressed on the keyboard.

I have tried both with `JavaScript` and `jQuery` but its not working and shows a null output.

How do i select the div of a particular data-attribute when the key is pressed?

Please see the code below:

### html

```
<div class="row-2">
    <div data-key="65" class="keys">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Js

```
    window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
      const here = document.querySelector('.keys[data-key="${e.keycode}"]');
      console.log(here);     
      });
```

---

### Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('html').on('keydown',function(event){
       var press = event.which;
       console.log(press);
       console.log(document.querySelector('.keys[data-key="${press}"]'));
       });
```

### });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! Just use the [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) with the value of `press` to get to the desired element.

The following demo highlights the key which was pressed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html').on('keydown', function(event) {
    var press = event.which;
    $(`div[data-key=${press}]`).addClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-2">
  <div data-key="65" class="keys">
    <kbd>A</kbd>
  </div>
  <div data-key="66" class="keys">
    <kbd>B</kbd>
  </div>
  <div data-key="67" class="keys">
    <kbd>C</kbd>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong string literal for your interpolation:

'.keys[data-key="${e.keycode}"]' should be `.keys[data-key="${e.keycode}"]`

Answer (score 0):

Just change this `.keys[data-key="${press}"]` for this `.keys[data-key="' + press + '"]`